# Read content from file which is in TFS with TFS API C#

Tags: c#, tfs, msbuild

Maybe is duplicate but I didn't find proper answer.

Is it possible to read content from file which is on TFS before MSBuild is started?

I am using following:

```
 TfsTeamProjectCollection server = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("https://hasinc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection"));
 VersionControlServer version = server.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer)) as VersionControlServer;   
 Item item = version.GetItem(@"$\SomeProject\SomeFile.cs");
```

I provided server path and I retrieved correct "item". I can read some properties e.g. content length. But how I can read file?

I need to read content and extract some specific info!

That process happening during TFS build in custom activity method:

```
protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
{
}
```

Is it possible to achieve that?

Comment: Which version of TFS Build are you using?

Comment: I am using TFS 2013.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some ideas on downloading the file:

**DownloadFile Method**

You could use the [DownloadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138502.aspx) method to download the file to a temporary file:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection server = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("https://hasinc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection"));
VersionControlServer version = server.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer)) as VersionControlServer;   
Item item = version.GetItem(@"$\SomeProject\SomeFile.cs");
string tempFileName = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
item.DownloadFile(tempFileName);
```

**DownloadFiles Activity**

Rather than getting the file in a custom activity, Team Build 2012 & 2013 both support a [DownloadFiles activity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg265783.aspx#Activity_Download_Files), which allows a customized build to download file(s) not in the workspace.

**Add an Extra Path to the Build Source Settings**

You could edit the **Source Settings** of your build definition, to map an additional source control folder to a build agent folder.